# AS3 - Copy image to clipboard

Tags: actionscript-3, clipboard

How to copy an image in AS3 to the clipboard? 
For text it works but I can't find a way to copy an image.

```
System.setClipboard("my text")
```

Comment: You could instead offer the ability to save a bitmap to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#setClipboard%28%29):

> Parameters
>
> string:String — A plain-text string of characters to put on the system
>   Clipboard, replacing its current contents (if any).

However, with Air you can use: [`Clipboard.setData()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#setData%28%29) instead.

Comment: I was hoping that there are some workarounds with the print-screen, Javascript or bytearray.

Comment: For me it's Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT, oBitmapData);